# Django 2.0.6 manage.py getting runserver error

Tags: django-2.0

I'm new on python and also try to learn a Django version 2.0.6 , so when i try to write the code with the documentation of Django here:

[image: here]

If faced a problem, specifically when I want to run the code, could help me to solve that issue please.
[image]

1- code (urls.py)folder polls:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.index, name= 'index'),

]
```

2- code (urls.py) folder mysite:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/',include('polls.Urls'))

]
```

3- code (views.py) folder mysite:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return  HttpResponse("Hi world, you are walcome")
```

Comment: Instead of screenshot, you must paste your code here.

Comment: done @catchingUp